# Angular rxjs async array undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, rxjs

There is a a `newData` array and rxjs `forkJoin` operator with two methods.
I'm trying to populate the array within `getNewData()` in order to use it in forkJoin subscription, but it's still undefined. Which would be the appropriate way to wait for newData array to be populated in `getNewData()` in order to use it in forkJoin subscription?

```
    newData = [];
    
    forkJoin(
      this.method1();
      this.method2()
    ).subscribe({ data1, data2 }) => {
       const filteredData = data1.filter(item => item.id === model.id);
       this.getNewData(filteredData);

       console.log(this.newData) => undefined

       // wait for this.newData?
    }

    // Observable
    getNewData(filteredData) {
      return this.API('GET', `data/${filteredData.id}`).pipe(map((resp: any) => {
          this.newData = resp;
        }));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting nested subscription which is discouraged.

<s>If the calls are entirely independent of each other, you could append `this.API('GET', 'data')` call as third argument to the `forkJoin` function.</s>

```js
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

newData = [];

forkJoin(
  this.method1(),
  this.method2(),
  this.API('GET', `data`)
).subscribe([ data1, data2, newData ]) => {
  const filteredData = data1.filter(item => item.id === model.id);
  this.newData = newData;
  console.log(this.newData);
}
```

Or if the API call somehow depends on the data from the first two methods, then you could use one of the RxJS higher order mapping operators like `switchMap`.

```js
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { swithcMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

newData = [];

forkJoin(
  this.method1(),
  this.method2()
).pipe(
  switchMap(([data1, data2]) => {
    const filteredData = data1.filter(item => item.id === model.id);
    return this.getNewData(filteredData);
  })
).subscribe(newData => {
  this.newData = newData;
  console.log(this.newData);
}

getNewData (filteredData): Observable<any> {
  return this.API('GET', `data/${filteredData.id}`).pipe(
    map((resp: any) => {
      this.newData = resp;
    })
  );
}
```

**Update (accd. to OP's update)**:

1. You wish to use the output from `forkJoin` inside another HTTP call. Then you'd need to `switchMap` operator as shown.
2. (Unrelated to the issue) Please try to provide notes like this when you update something in the original post. It makes it easier to understand your intent.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add method `getNewData` to `forkjoin` as third argument, and you will have newData inside your sub

```
    forkJoin(
      this.method1();
      this.method2(), 
      this.getNewData() 
    ).subscribe([ data1, data2 , newData]) => {
       const filteredData = data1.filter(item => item.id === model.id);
      
    }

    // Observable
    getNewData() {
      return this.API('GET', `data`)
    }
```

**Why you changed your question?**

**now our answers are not correct - do not do so**

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

```
forkJoin(
 this.method1(),
 this.method2()
)
 .pipe(
   map(([data1, data2]) => {
     const filterData = [data1, data2]; // here will be some filtereing
     return filterData;
   }),
   mergeMap(filteredData => {
     // here you can append your filterData
     return this.getNewData(filteredData);
   })
 )
 .subscribe(console.log);

   getNewData(filterData) {
     return this.API('GET', filterData)
   }
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-j7rrwl?file=index.ts

Comment: If my answer helps you, you can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1):

Use `combineLatest` from RxJS and use `filter(), tap()` to check for the data

```
combineLatest(
    this.method1(),
    this.method2(),
    this.getNewData()
).pipe(
    filter(data => !!data), 
    tap(data => console.log(data)) 
    catchError(error => console.log(error))
).subscribe(
  [dataFromMethod1, dataFromMethod2, dataFromMethod3] => {
   // This will subscribe only if all the observables return data
   // Otherwise it will go to catchError
})


// Filter will check if the data is present or not.
// Tap will return the data before subscribing
// catchError ==> Subscription errors are caught in this catchError
```

Comment: I've updated to the question; there is a `filteredData` which need to be passed to `getNewData` method so in that case I think it would be appropriate to use `switchMap` as @Michael D suggested

Comment: That makes sense!